# Xamarin android messing up resource handles

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm encountering a certain issue that's rather annoying.

Whenever I edit anything having to do with resources, Xamarin messes up the resource handles. So, assuming that string resource Resource.String.AStringResource has handle 2131034119 "normally", Xamarin messes this and uses another resource handle entirely (which could be e.g. the handle to an assembly!).

Performing a "Clean all" makes the issue go away until the next time I need to edit a resource (layout, string, add/remove an image, whatever).

Has anyone else encountered the same?

Comment: How are you editing your resource handles?

Are you editing the relevant XML and letting Xamarin regenerate Resource.designer.cs?
Are you manually editing Resource.designer.cs?

How are you using those resource handles? Could you give a example of your code?

Comment: I let xamarin regenerate the Resource.Designer.cs. It **seems** to be regenerating it **correctly** each time.

Comment: If Xamarin is regenerating Resource.Designer.cs and seems to do it correctly each time, then I'm unsure what the problem is. How are you using those handles that changes in them are a problem?

Comment: Typically something along the line of GetString(Resource.String.AStringResource). When the issue occurs, the output is a **different** string resource most of the time. Once I saw the name of an assembly.

Comment: Well, with the obvious stuff out of the way I must admit I don't really know what could be causing this. Could you check whether the issue also occurs in a new project? If so we can at least rule out a malformed .csproj file. Could you also check whether a 'Clean All' empties the entire obj/ directory?

Comment: Maybe this person is having the same issue?

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23116/changing-android-resource-file-regenerates-resource-designer-cs-differently-than-full-build#latest

Comment: @Frank Hehe, nice how we've made a kinda infinite loop there. BTW, I'm not the poster in the Xamarin forum, so it's somewhat comforting that someone else is having the same issue.

Comment: Also, when I see the issue reappear I'll make sure to check the obj folder before and after the clean and report back here.

Comment: No it doesn't clear the obj folder (I just added an imageview to a layout and the issue reappeared. A Clean all made it go away again).